# ASP email client to write and read mails from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, email

I have a requirement where i need to create a simple email client using ASP.NET web application.
Currently there exists a service which can send emails from reading email from database and it can retrieve email from email source and save it in database(SQL server 2008).So now i only need a client which can read and write these emails to database.It should have simple functions like inbox,reply,forward,reply all,delete,search email etc.

So now I want a simple design which includes all these features.I saw some [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/webmail/) but they are much complex and not free. So can anyone help me with the design part of this web application or any articles or examples showing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third party tools(.dll) like openPop.net (Open sources),EAGetMail (Premium version) for read and write email to database.

below links would be  help you:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188349/Read-Gmail-Inbox-Message-in-ASP-NET
2. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-read-email-messages-with-attachments-from-GMAIL-POP3-mail-server-in-ASPNet.aspx
3. http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/reading-gmail-inbox-using-aspnet

Comment: Is there any ready code which has simple design like Gmail (inbox and reply features)?